# Not getting desire output

Tags: php

What I want to do is,
I am initializing `$message` variable for mail body.

And I has to iterate through loop if multiple files are there.
So how can i iterate loop and store values in a variable.

Like,

```
$message = "Dear " . $fname . "  <br/>        
<b>Manuscript and Other Documents :</b> <br/>
Source File : " .$file1 . " <br/>
Source PDF File : ".$file2 . " <br/>
Cover Letter : " . $file3 . "<br/>
Supplementary Files : " . while($row=mysql_fetch_array($supplementary)){ echo $row[0] } . ";
```

So how can i do this if i have multiple supplementary files?

Comment: use string concatenation operator dot(.) like $message .= "....", check http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: assign your supplimentary file names to a variable with the loop, and append that variable to $message wherever you want it

Answer (score 0):

To do this, simply append the data to the message variable within the while loop using the [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

For example:

```
$message = "Dear " . $fname . "  <br/><b>Manuscript and Other Documents :</b><br/>
Source File : " .$file1 . "<br/>Source PDF File : ".$file2 . " <br/>
Cover Letter : " . $file3 . "<br/>Supplementary Files : ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($supplementary)) {
    $message .= echo $row[0] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do this:

```
$suplArray = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($supplementary)){
    $suplArray[] =  $row[0];
}
```

Now, you have the strings in an array. I don't know what format you want, but you can do something like

```
$suplStr = implode(',', $suplArray);
```

Then in your string, you can have:

```
... "Supplementary Files : " . $suplStr;
```

Comment: it gives last filename only.